# PHP check csv column with strpos

Tags: php, validation

I need to check the csv column (string) if contain some words. Then add it to the array of csv. Here is my current code.

example csv

```
     A            B
 1   Order Number Order Items
 2   100001       foo - sbar - ybaz - z
 3   100002       foo - sbar - ybaz - z
```

This is my code.

```
$csv = array_map( "str_getcsv", file( /path/to/csv/, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES ) );
$keys = array_shift($csv);

$values = ["foo - s", "baz - z"];

foreach ($csv as $key => $row) {
    $csv[$key] = array_combine( $keys, $row )

    foreach ($values as $value) {

        if (strpos($row[0], $value) !==FALSE) {
            $csv[$key][$keys[1]] = $value;
        }

    }

}
```

This is what i want to achieve.

```
[0] => 
array(2) => {
    ["Order Number"] => "100001"
    ["Order Items"] =>
    array (2) {
        [0] => "foo - x",
        [1] => "baz - z"
    }
}
[1] => 
    array(2) => {
        ["Order Number"] => "100002"
        ["Order Items"] =>
        array (2) {
            [0] => "foo - x",
            [1] => "baz - z"
        }
    }
```

This is what my code output

```
[0] => 
array(2) => {
    ["Order Number"] => "100001"
    ["Order Items"] => "baz - z"
}
[1] => 
    array(2) => {
        ["Order Number"] => "100002"
        ["Order Items"] => "baz - z"
    }
```

if i add and make this `$csv[$i][$keys[1]][] = $value;`

This error show: `Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings`

Comment: are you sure that $row is a string with column name??

Comment: Yes sorry. I added information on my code. Please take a look

Comment: `$csv[$i] = array_combine...` What is $i ?

Comment: @splash58 sorry wrong input gonna edit it to $key

Comment: And there - `$csv[$i][$keys[1]] ` ?

Comment: @splash58 oops. Ok thanks. Changing it to $key. But it is just a typo. Code is working tho.

Comment: Look there - where i am wrong - https://eval.in/907616

Comment: Sorry this is the $csv variable contain.

`$csv = array_map( "str_getcsv", file( /path/to/example/csv/, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES ) );`

Comment: `var_export($csv);`Is it not the same as in my example?

Comment: @splash58 nope. it contains the array of csv.

Comment: https://eval.in/907624 Let's reproduce your result

Comment: @splash58 https://eval.in/907623 but i dont know how to add it on $csv variable.

Comment: Look there - https://eval.in/907659

Comment: @splash58 Hi, Thanks for your effort. Could you post it as an answer so i can upvote it?

Comment: I've written it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add one more loop to scan row values

```
$csv = array_map( "str_getcsv", file('php://stdin', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES ) );
$keys = array_shift($csv);

$values = ["foo - s", "baz - z"];

foreach ($csv as $key => $row) {
    $csv[$key] = array_combine( $keys, $row );
    foreach($row as $k=>$i) {
       foreach ($values as $value) {
          if (strpos($i, $value) !==FALSE) {
              if (! is_array($csv[$key][$keys[1]])) $csv[$key][$keys[1]] = [];
              $csv[$key][$keys[1]][] = $value;
          }
        }  
    }
}
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/907659)